# jquery event update input triggered on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update input value from jquery ajax request and some other labels but the input is not updated only after the second click. I've searched for answer and i got that maybe the input lose foucs and when i click again the input is refocued again,but i can't figure out how to set foucs again on the input

Here is my code :

```
$(oe_website_sale).on('click', 'li.installment_term', function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var term_id = $('li.installment_term.active').attr('id');
            var $parent = $ul.closest('.js_product');
            var price = $parent.find(".oe_price:first .oe_currency_value")[0].innerText;
            var down_payment = $('input.down_payment');
            ajax.jsonRpc('/calculate/term/load', 'call', {term_id, price})
                .done(function (result) {
                    price_install.text(result.price_per_month);// This line is updating perfectly from the first click
                    down_payment.val(result.down_payment); // This line has now effect only after second click
                    down_payment.attr('min', result.down_payment);// This line is updating perfectly from the first click
                });

        });
```

and my html code :

```
<input type="number" name="down_payment" min="0" step="0.01"
                                   class="form-control down_payment" value="0.00"/>
```

Comment: please share the 'input.down_payment' html code

Comment: @Rajesh i have updated my code

Comment: the code looks fine, just confirm the value of  'result.down_payment' property whether it has the valid value for all the time.

Comment: I figured out the problem,the problem was with term_id = $('li.installment_term.active').attr('id'); .. this line of code does not get the clicked li id but get the last clicked li id .. so when i click first time it get wrong term value

Thanks @Rajesh